# PHP 5.6 got error SSH2

Tags: php, ssh

I tried ro execute SSH2 using PHP 5.6, but i got an error

**No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in Net/SSH2.php**

It happened when i upgrade PHP 5.4 to 5.6, can anyone tell me how to solve it ?

here's my source

```
set_include_path(__DIR__ . '/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
include('Net/SSH2.php');    
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.48.51.118');
if (!$ssh->login('nfc', '@fb204')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
```

**error** `No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found in Net/SSH2.php`

Comment: Either your server or Net/SSH2 library does not support reasonable ciphers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the discussion thread here https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/issues/434#issuecomment-50597527 it might help you to solve your issue.

You need to set include path for your SSH file

Comment: No no. you will have to set include path first. before including file. so sequence would be like set_include_path and then include statements

Comment: Try to echo/print __DIR__ . '/' . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path() this path and make sure it gives you the exact document path of Net/SSH2.php file. if not, then you will have to modify your set include path.

the thing is, we are setting path for file include means your include tag include('Net/SSH2.php');  can find appropriate location for your file. what is document path of your SSH2.php file?